# Is the service account mandatory for google app marketplace listing

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We are trying to list our app in google app marketplace, and it is domain installable app. Is the creation of service account mandatory in this case?

Answer (score -1):

[https://firebase.google.com/`](https://firebase.google.com/%60)

> *emphasized text*google.com/
> ://

- publish/

`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).